# ES6 - Invoking callback with argument from base class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm trying to encapsulate common functionality in base class and planning to invoke derived class specific function from their respective instances. Somehow, I'm not getting parameters in derived class. not sure what's wrong here -

```
class A {
  constructor(callback){
    this.callback = callback;
  }
  
  write(){
    console.log('Writing A');
    this.callback(10);
  }
  
}

class B extends A {
  
  constructor(){
    super(()=> this.read())
  }
  
  read(n){
    console.log('Read B: ' + n);
  }  
}

const b = new B();
b.write();
```

**Output**

```
"Writing A"
"Read B: undefined"
```

Whereas, I would expect -

```
"Writing A"
"Read B: 10"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
super(()=> this.read())
```

The callback takes no parameters, and passes nothing along to `this.read` - so the `10` gets lost.

Make sure the callback takes the required parameter and passes it.

```js
class A {
  constructor(callback){
    this.callback = callback;
  }
  
  write(){
    console.log('Writing A');
    this.callback(10);
  }
  
}

class B extends A {
  
  constructor(){
    super((n)=> this.read(n))
  }
  
  read(n){
    console.log('Read B: ' + n);
  }  
}

const b = new B();
b.write();
```

More generically, with spread:

```js
class A {
  constructor(callback){
    this.callback = callback;
  }
  
  write(){
    console.log('Writing A');
    this.callback(10);
  }
  
}

class B extends A {
  
  constructor(){
    super((...args)=> this.read(...args))
  }
  
  read(n){
    console.log('Read B: ' + n);
  }  
}

const b = new B();
b.write();
```

Comment: I did try `super(() => this.read(n))` but `super(**(n)** => this.read(n))` was the trick. You caught me. Thank you!

Comment: @Codie please mark this post as the answer in order to avoid other people to come here and try to solve a problem that's already solved. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can pass a [*bound* function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and don't have to think about forwarding the arguments:

```
super(this.read.bind(this));
```